# How to prevent "SSL Certificate Chain Not Sorted"

Tags: https

I just got an message SSL Certificate Chain Not Sorted when I scanned my server configuration...I am not sure how to order or sort the certificates.

I have a SSL certificate and intermediate certificates as well. And, I have configured them in apache. But not sure what is the right order or how to sort these certificates.

Comment: I'd be interested in reproducing the error if anyone can provide details on how this could happen.

Comment: @makerofthings7: to reproduce this is fairly easy if you have a certificate with a intermediate CA cert in the chain on an Apache Httpd server. Check the files where it's configured `SSLCertificateChainFile` or `SSLCertificateFile` and swap the order of the PEM blocks.

Answer (score 3):

The certificate chain presented by the server should be sorted according to the [TLS Specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4346#section-7.4.2):

> **certificate_list**
>
> This is a sequence (chain) of X.509v3 certificates.  The sender's
> certificate must come first in the list.  Each following
> certificate must directly certify the one preceding it.  Because
> certificate validation requires that root keys be distributed
> independently, the self-signed certificate that specifies the root
> certificate authority may optionally be omitted from the chain,
> under the assumption that the remote end must already possess it
> in order to validate it in any case.

You can check the list that is presented using `openssl s_client -connect your.host.name:443`, for example. Taking `www.github.com` as an example, you should get something like this:

```
Certificate chain
 0 s:/O=*.github.com/OU=Domain Control Validated/CN=*.github.com
   i:/C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=GoDaddy.com, Inc./OU=http://certificates.godaddy.com/repository/CN=Go Daddy Secure Certification Authority/serialNumber=07969287
 1 s:/C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=GoDaddy.com, Inc./OU=http://certificates.godaddy.com/repository/CN=Go Daddy Secure Certification Authority/serialNumber=07969287
   i:/C=US/O=The Go Daddy Group, Inc./OU=Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority
 2 s:/C=US/O=The Go Daddy Group, Inc./OU=Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority
   i:/L=ValiCert Validation Network/O=ValiCert, Inc./OU=ValiCert Class 2 Policy Validation Authority/CN=http://www.valicert.com//emailAddress=info@valicert.com
 3 s:/L=ValiCert Validation Network/O=ValiCert, Inc./OU=ValiCert Class 2 Policy Validation Authority/CN=http://www.valicert.com//emailAddress=info@valicert.com
   i:/L=ValiCert Validation Network/O=ValiCert, Inc./OU=ValiCert Class 2 Policy Validation Authority/CN=http://www.valicert.com//emailAddress=info@valicert.com
```

The issuer of a certificate in the chain should be the subject of the next certificate.

The order presented by the server matches the order in which you've put the certificates in PEM format in the Apache Httpd configuration files.

Either you chain them all in the file referred to by `SSLCertificateFile`, or you only put your server certificate there and put the rest of the chain, in order, in a separate file referred to by `SSLCertificateChainFile`.

To check which PEM fragment (between `--... BEGIN/END ...--`), copy them in separate `.pem` file and check what your favourite PEM viewer says, or paste the fragment in the standard input of `openssl x509 -text -noout`.